# Suggestion for improvement in site look

Tags: feature-request

The current evolution of the SU site look has created a sidebar
that is mostly empty space :

[image: now]

It seems to me that it would be useful to transfer more information
to the sidebar, in order to avoid the need for scrolling up in the page
for the purpose of moving to another section of the display.

There is also a functionally strange point, that "Unanswered", which is
really a sub-section of "Questions", is currently displayed twice,
the second time in the sidebar on the same level as is "Questions".

Here is an example of what I think would be a functionally logical look
for the sidebar :

[image: suggestion]

Comment: I like it. But doesn't this belong on Meta.SE?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Perhaps, we'll see how it goes,

Comment: OK, some upvotes, no comments, so posting on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316356/suggestion-for-improvement-in-site-look-sidebar).